# javascript show calculated total amount on div on on text field

Tags: javascript

I am calculating the total amount due based on selected QTY from user. 
Everything is working except for one thing. The total only displays on a input field eg.

```
<input id="total" type="text" readonly />
```

Here is my code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function CalculateTotal() { 
    var qty = document.getElementById('Number').value;
    var price = 50; 
    var result = document.getElementById("total"); 
    result.value = price * qty;
}
```

TOTAL IS: `<input id="total" type="text" readonly />`. **This works.**

How can I show the total on a `<SPAN> or <DIV>`. I tried this `<span id="total" class="total">0</span>` but it doesn't do anything. Can anyone help?

Comment: Id's must be unique...

Comment: pick a unique id and use .innerHTML method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.value` which only applies to form fields.  If you use `.innerHTML` you can set the contents of a `span` or `div`.

So you'd have:

```
result.innerHTML = price * qty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Such elements like `<SPAN> or <DIV>` doesn't have `value` attribute.
Try to use `innerHTML`

`result.value = price * qty;`

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
result.innerHTML = price * qty;
```

The "cleaner" way (if you need the text node as dom element at your disposal)

```
var text = result.childNodes[0];
if(text) {
    text.nodeValue = price * qty;
}
else {
    result.appendChild(document.createTextNode(price * qty));
}
```